# How can I open Telerik ReportView in Telerik Window

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-reporting

I want to open Telerik Report inside Telerik Window and also i want to fetch report view to another view ?

I also tried in my application I used Telerik().Window() inside Telerik().ReportView but then my js files crushed? I tried to create window from javascript but then myWindow undefined?

How can i do this?

Dou  you have any idea or suggestion for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials and read some articles i found how to open Telerik Report Viewer in Telerik Window

I just put my js and css files on my page and then basically i put my reporting codes inside window content and it works!!!

Here codes

```
 @{ Html.Telerik().Window()
        .Name("Reportwin")
        .Title("Report")
        .Buttons(b => b.Close())
        .Content(@<text>
         @{
             UriReportSource trial = new UriReportSource();
             trial.Uri = "Report.trdx";
             trial.Parameters.Add("Id", Session["Id"].ToString());

          }
          @(Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
          .Id("reportViewer1")
          .ServiceUrl("/api/reports/")
          .TemplateUrl("/Reports/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html")
          .ReportSource(trial)
          .ViewMode(ViewModes.INTERACTIVE)
          .ScaleMode(ScaleModes.SPECIFIC)
          .Scale(1.0)
          .PersistSession(false)
           )
        </text>)
         .Modal(true)
         .Visible(false)
         .Draggable(true)
         .Width(1300)
         .Height(700)
         .Resizable()
         .Render();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works in MVC, however this is how I do it in ASP.

Place your report in a report viewer on a page and and open the RadWindow on such page.
I mean: Your reportViewer in page_report pointing to the report.
Your window in another page:

```
 function openRadWin() {
                var width = "430px";
                var height = "355px";
                var left = "800px";
                var top = "150px";
                radopen("page_report.aspx", "RadWindow1", width, height, left, top);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @FeliceM i'm not using RadControls i'm using MVC controls and actually i dont understand so much your answer what is mean radopen()?? I found some examples but its not useful for me

Comment: My understanding is that you would like to open a window with the report inside. If so, the above script open a Radwindow pointing to the page where the report is instantiated. It works for me in ASP.

Comment: Oh Ok i understand you but also i found to way open report in window now i will put answer here thank you for your comments and suggessions